# em editor multi line entry by user through text input window

Tags: emeditor

i want to enter multi line of 10 lines with adjustable window width? is it possible to achieve the same with a macro?
i want to read the multi line into a string variable.
i want user input window should  come with OK, Cancel buttons and the text entered should be read into a string variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to EmEditor v20.3 beta 4 (20.2.904), and use this form:

`strAnswer = prompt( "message", "default", eePromptMultiline );`

Comment: hello sir, the font size in single/multiline text box is very small. to overcome this problem i am activating grabtext window by pressing shortcut control+alt+b from the textbox. now whatever data i am typing in grabtext window gets appeared in the prompt text box once grabtext window is closed. is there any way that grabtext window is called automatically the moment prompt prompt( "message", "default", eePromptMultiline ); is executed? basically the shortcut control+alt+b should get pressed automatically from the text box of prompt window.